# how to show 'recently visited'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a web app that has user profiles, where users can search for fellow users based on interests, as well as post + attend events etc.. How might I add a feature where users can see who 'Recently visited' a certain event?

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :location, :date, :time, :event_date

  acts_as_commentable
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :event_participants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participants, through: :event_participants, source: :user

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter, :linkedin]

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :zip, :gender, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name,
                  :birthday, :current_password, :occupation, :address, :interests, :aboutme, :profile_image,
                  :photos_attributes, :age, :education, :ethnicity

  has_many :authorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments
  has_many :events
  has_many :photos, as: :attachable
  has_many :questions
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :receiver_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
  mount_uploader :profile_image, ProfileImageUploader

end
```

**event_participants.rb**

```
class EventParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :event_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :event_id}

end
```

**events_controller snippit**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = current_user
    @events = Event.all
    @interesting_people = @users.order("random()").first(5)

  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @users = User.all
    @user = current_user
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @event
    @comment = @event.comments.new
    @interesting_people = @users.order("random()").first(5)
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code, it looks like you could do something like:

```
@event.event_participants.include(:users).order('created_at desc').limit(X).map(&:user)
```

You could also try without the `include`:

```
@event.event_participants.order('created_at desc').limit(X).map(&:user)
```

But that will do N+1 queries. The `join` will perform better.

Where in the above code, `X` would be how many participants you want to show.

Comment: I'm getting a "undefined method `participants'" error. Bare in mind I'm running your code on the event#show page.

Comment: added the relevant part of events_controller might help.

Comment: See my updated answer.  `join` on `users` To make it a single SQL query.

Comment: Second thought, you want `include` not `join` because you already have many `event_participants`...  Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: It's like 95% there, can we show the user.name though? as it's returning the user record.

Comment: that's perfect, only thing is - it returns in an array in the view? i.e. ['Jack'] can it return just the name?

Comment: No, because with the `event_participants`, you have an array already.  You'll want to iterate over that array to show individual names.

Comment: Gotcha.. okay damn. Idealy i'd like to show the profile_image of the user but won't be able to this way I don't think. As it returns the full record.

Comment: Sure you could, since you have an array of user objects being returned.  If you iterate over them, you can show anything you want for each user.